# nearest distance between a point and line segment

Tags: python, math, geometry, coordinates

Given a line with coordinates 'start' and 'end' and the coordinates of a point 'pnt' find the shortest distance from pnt to the line. I have tried the below code.

```
    import math

def dot(v,w):
    x,y,z = v
    X,Y,Z = w
    return x*X + y*Y + z*Z

def length(v):
    x,y,z = v
    return math.sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z)

def vector(b,e):
    x,y,z = b
    X,Y,Z = e
    return (X-x, Y-y, Z-z)

def unit(v):
    x,y,z = v
    mag = length(v)
    return (x/mag, y/mag, z/mag)

def distance(p0,p1):
    return length(vector(p0,p1))

def scale(v,sc):
    x,y,z = v
    return (x * sc, y * sc, z * sc)

def add(v,w):
    x,y,z = v
    X,Y,Z = w
    return (x+X, y+Y, z+Z)




def pnt2line(pnt, start, end):
    line_vec = vector(start, end)
    pnt_vec = vector(start, pnt)
    line_len = length(line_vec)
    line_unitvec = unit(line_vec)
    pnt_vec_scaled = scale(pnt_vec, 1.0/line_len)
    t = dot(line_unitvec, pnt_vec_scaled)    
    if t < 0.0:
        t = 0.0
    elif t > 1.0:
        t = 1.0
    nearest = scale(line_vec, t)
    dist = distance(nearest, pnt_vec)
    nearest = add(nearest, start)
    return (dist, nearest)
```

Comment: It could be more helpful if you could provide some sample in/outputs and your attempt.

Comment: What is "a point"? x,y? x,y,z?

Comment: its a 2-D space, (x,y)

Comment: Okay, and what is your question about this code? Is there a particular problem with it? If so, what is it?

Comment: the code I have shared is for 3D space but I am implementing in 2D space. So can you pls help with the code for 2D space.

Comment: Can you show how this code isn't working as intended for 2D space?

Comment: If anything, you could just set `z=0` for every `z` coordinate.

Comment: "I have tried the below code.": we are glad for you, but what is your question ?

Comment: I have removed the zcordinate and given only x and y, the results are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The resolution can be explained by the figure, which shows the locus of the points at a given distance from a segment. It is made of two half circles and two line segments, which are separated by the two perpendiculars at the endpoints.

[image]

We can simplify the discussion by ensuring that the segment is in a canonical position, with endpoints (0, 0) and (L, 0). For any segment, we can apply a similarity transformation to bring it in the canonical position (see below), and move the target point accordingly.

Now the computation of the distance amounts to

```
    X < 0 -> √[X² + Y²]
0 ≤ X ≤ L -> |Y|
L < X     -> √[(X-L)² + Y²]
```

---

- Subtract the coordinates of one endpoint from all points to bring the segment to the origin.
- Compute the length `L`.
- Normalize the vector to the second endpoint to obtain a unit vector, let `U`.
- Transform the target point with `X' = Ux.X + Uy.Y`, `Y' = Ux.Y - Uy.X`.

---

Technical remark:

The geometric analysis proves that the output function is the square root of a piecewise quadratic function and it takes one or two comparisons to tell the active piece and this cannot be avoided. If I am right, the algebraic expressions cannot be much simpified.